# Index field with all same value. Is this bad?

Tags: index, index-tuning

I have the following index

`create unique index open_issues_unique on issue (status, type, reference_id) where status = 'OPEN';`

This means the value of the column status will always be `OPEN`.
Does this have a negative impact on the index performance? Can I simply remove `status` from the index as I have the where clause?

Comment: You may either remove this column from the index expression or move it to the end if the expression (this can be useful when the index is covering one for a query).